# What is "Usage" in relation to Microsoft Azure billing

Tags: c#, azure, billing

this might be a stupid question but I have to ask.  I've never used Azure before but a client is looking to send some SQL databases and their web server to the cloud.  On the Azure site they refer to billing for usage per hour.

If I create 10 SQL Databases, is usage considered the actual amount of time they were used by the application, or am I charged for the amount of time I had the database instances themselves?  Same with a web application...if the web application goes 2 weeks without any web traffic, does that still count as usage since I have the app live in Azure? If the app is not used then the databases wouldn't be either, so both would be idle and not used at the moment.

I guess I'm just confused as to what the word "usage" is actually referring to.

Comment: contact microsoft. they have a good sales team that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meaning of `Usage` in Azure varies based on the type of resource. For some items, usage is calculated in terms of consumed hours (websites, virtual machines etc. would come there) whereas for certain items it is calculated in terms of consumed space (azure storage is a good example of that).

Also, please note that pricing is not based on the utilization (e.g. how many times a website got hit) but based on provisioning. So in your example, if a website is provisioned for you, you will pay for it irrespective of the fact that anybody is using that website or not.

I would recommend taking a look at [`Azure Pricing Calculator`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to understand approximately how much are you going to pay by resource type.